# Consistent FPS in frame by frame video with <canvas>

Tags: javascript, video, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to display precisely enough a video that I can **stop on or jump to a specific frame**. For now my approach is to display a video frame by frame on a canvas (I do have the list of images to display, I don't have to extract them from the video). The speed doesn't really matter **as long as it's consistent** and around 30fps. Compatibility somewhat matters (we can ignore IE≤8).

So first off, I'm pre-loading all the images:

```
var all_images_loaded = {};
var all_images_src = ["Continuity_0001.png","Continuity_0002.png", ..., "Continuity_0161.png"];

function init() {
    for (var i = all_images_src.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var objImage = new Image();
        objImage.onload = imagesLoaded;
        objImage.src = 'Continuity/'+all_images_src[i];
        all_images_loaded[all_images_src[i]] = objImage;
    }
}

var loaded_count = 0;
function imagesLoaded () {
    console.log(loaded_count + " / " + all_images_src.length);
    if(++loaded_count === all_images_src.length) startvid();
}

init();
```

and once that's done, the function `startvid()` is called.

---

Then the first solution I came up with was to draw on `requestAnimationFrame()` after a `setTimeout` (to tame the fps):

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var video_pointer = 0;
function startvid () {
    video_pointer++;
    if(all_images_src[video_pointer]){
        window.requestAnimationFrame((function (video_pointer) {
            ctx.drawImage(all_images_loaded[all_images_src[video_pointer]], 0, 0);
        }).bind(undefined, video_pointer))
        setTimeout(startvid, 33);
    }
}
```

but that felt somewhat slow and irregular...

---

So second solution is to use 2 canvases and draw on the one being `hidden` and then switch it to `visible` with the proper timing:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
var ctx = [canvas[0].getContext("2d"), canvas[1].getContext("2d")];

var curr_can_is_0 = true;
var video_pointer = 0;
function startvid () {
    video_pointer++;
    curr_can_is_0 = !curr_can_is_0;
    if(all_images_src[video_pointer]){
        ctx[curr_can_is_0?1:0].drawImage(all_images_loaded[all_images_src[video_pointer]], 0, 0);

        window.requestAnimationFrame((function (curr_can_is_0, video_pointer) {
            ctx[curr_can_is_0?0:1].canvas.style.visibility = "visible";
            ctx[curr_can_is_0?1:0].canvas.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }).bind(undefined, curr_can_is_0, video_pointer));

        setTimeout(startvid, 33);
    }
}
```

but that too feels slow and irregular...

---

Yet, Google Chrome (which I'm developing on) seems to have plenty of idle time:
[image: Chrome Dev Tools, timeline 1]
[image: Chrome Dev Tools, timeline 2]
[image: Chrome Dev Tools, timeline 3]

So what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem:

Your main issue is [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) and [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) are not guaranteed to fire at exactly the delay specified, but at some point after the delay.

From [the MDN article on `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) (emphasis added by me).

> delay is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the function call should be delayed by. If omitted, it defaults to 0. **The actual delay may be longer**; see Notes below.

Here are the relevant notes from MDN mentioned above.

> Historically browsers implement setTimeout() "clamping": successive setTimeout() calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay, DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE, is 4 ms (stored in a preference in Firefox: dom.min_timeout_value), with a DOM_CLAMP_TIMEOUT_NESTING_LEVEL of 5.
>
> In fact, 4ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested timeouts was 10 ms.
>
> In addition to "clamping", the timeout can also fire later when the page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks.

## The Solution:

You would be better off using just [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), and inside the callback using the `timestamp` arguments passed to the callback to compute the delta time into the video, and drawing the necessary frame from the list. See working example below. As a bonus, I've even included code to prevent re-drawing the same frame twice.

### Working Example:

```js
var start_time = null;
var frame_rate = 30;

var canvas = document.getElementById('video');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var all_images_loaded = {};
var all_images_src = (function(frames, fps){//Generate some placeholder images.
 var a = [];
 var zfill = function(s, l) {
  s = '' + s;
  while (s.length < l) {
   s = '0' + s;
  }
  return s;
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
  a[i] = 'http://placehold.it/480x270&text=' + zfill(Math.floor(i / fps), 2) + '+:+' + zfill(i % fps, 2)
 }
 return a;
})(161, frame_rate);

var video_duration = (all_images_src.length / frame_rate) * 1000;

function init() {
 for (var i = all_images_src.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var objImage = new Image();
  objImage.onload = imagesLoaded;
  //objImage.src = 'Continuity/'+all_images_src[i];
  objImage.src = all_images_src[i];
  all_images_loaded[all_images_src[i]] = objImage;
 }
}

var loaded_count = 0;
function imagesLoaded () {
    //console.log(loaded_count + " / " + all_images_src.length);
    if (++loaded_count === all_images_src.length) {
  startvid();
 }
}

function startvid() {
 requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

var last_frame = null;
function draw(timestamp) {
 //Set the start time on the first call.
 if (!start_time) {
  start_time = timestamp;
 }
 //Find the current time in the video.
 var current_time = (timestamp - start_time);
 //Check that it is less than the end of the video.
 if (current_time < video_duration) {
  //Find the delta of the video completed.
  var delta = current_time / video_duration;
  //Find the frame for that delta.
  var current_frame = Math.floor(all_images_src.length * delta);
  //Only draw this frame if it is different from the last one.
  if (current_frame !== last_frame) {
   ctx.drawImage(all_images_loaded[all_images_src[current_frame]], 0, 0);
   last_frame = current_frame;
  }
  //Continue the animation loop.
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 }
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="video" width="480" height="270"></canvas>
```

Comment: In this case, shouldn't you be using the timestamp provided as an argument of the callback function called by `requestAnimationFrame()`?

Comment: @Sheraff You could possibly use it if you want to, but it's not quite the same as `Date.now()`. It's a float, and is not zero-based to the first `requestAnimationFrame` call, so `Date.now()` is still necessary to get the start time. I also want to say some early implementations did not pass the delta time argument.

Comment: Or I could use a first `requestAnimationFrame` to get the start time and then there is no need for a `Date.now()`. Would that make any difference (more lightweight, more precise, ...)?

Comment: @Sheraff That thought actually just crossed my mind. I've switch the code to use the timestamp argument. It's probably slightly more accurate and slightly more-efficient this way, but not significantly.

Comment: Awesome :-) Where can I find implementation statistics to know which browsers actually implement this argument? You said before early implementations didn't pass it...

Comment: [Here's some information on it](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision) and [a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671). It looks like it was actually just a change in precision.

Comment: Great answer thanks. I'll leave it unaccepted for now, just as a fair chance for any other potential answer, but I'll give it to you in a day or so.